# Perldl failing to plot. Gnuplot fails to deploy with cpan

Tags: perl, plot, gnuplot, strawberry-perl, pdl

Started separated topic with clean new install as suggested by Håkon Hægland.
For those who are interested in solution, skip to end.
Gnuplot failing to install. Problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921340/perl-pdl-graphics-fails-to-show-image-as-specified-in-documentation)
Now removed all perl and started from clean install.
Using strawberry perl pdl edition, from zip package strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-PDL, no msi.
First according to [Documentation for PDL First Steps](https://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps).
I ran `cpan PDL::Graphics::Simple`.
Looks like successful.
Now run perldl according to [Documentation for PDL First Steps](https://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps)

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Simple
PDL::Graphics::Simple::register: PDL::Graphics::Simple::Prima is out of date - winging it at perlhome/perl/site/lib/PDL/Graphics/Simple.pm line 1397, <DATA> line 209.
pdl>imag (sin(rvals(200,200)+1))
Trying gnuplot (PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot)...nope
Trying pgplot (PDL::Graphics::PGPLOT::Window)...nope
Trying plplot (PDL::Graphics::PLplot)...nope
Trying prima (PDL::Graphics::Prima)...nope
Sorry, all known plotting engines failed.  Install one and try again.
```

So, first warning went not according to [Documentation for PDL First Steps](https://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps). The further errors after calling `imag (sin(rvals(200,200)+1))` went also not according to documentation. Test any plot

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot;
Can't locate PDL/Graphics/Gnuplot.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot module) (@INC contains: perlhome/perl/site/lib perlhome/perl/vendor/lib perlhome/perl/lib) at (eval 61) line 4, <DATA> line 209.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 61) line 4, <DATA> line 209.
```

Already knowing in advance is no plot installed, proceeding to install gnuplot, first one on  the list.

```
cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot
```

Comment: That output you link to at the end isn't for `cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot`.

Comment: @briandfoy  I clicked on link and it opened what was for ```cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot```, see **UPDATE 1** The link in fact contains two files, each one by # in the URL. If you do not see the correct file, then check for the second one. Maybe your browser doesn't want to jump to correct anchor.

Comment: *"Looks like successful"* : Regarding installation of `PDL::Graphics::Simple` : from [the log](https://gist.github.com/armagedescu/2a819848d8bdc6057a707a86cedb97ac#file-pdlgraphicssimple-txt-L7) I can see that there was some errors with downloading, but it seems like the module installed fine in the end? For comparison, I also did a fresh install of Strawberry Perl with PDL, and then installed PDL::Graphics::Simple. [Here](https://pastebin.com/8N10F6ft) is my install log.

Comment: Regarding [the install errors](https://gist.github.com/armagedescu/2a819848d8bdc6057a707a86cedb97ac) for PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot, I tried the same install and it succeeded. [Here](https://pastebin.com/PFZHmYwj) is my install log for comparison.

Comment: What version of Gnuplot did you install? And which terminals does it support? [Here](https://pastebin.com/3fZi41ua) is that information for my machine

Comment: @HåkonHægland **About PDL""Grahics::Simple** I did the diff between your output and mine, check **UPDATE 2**. Script tried http://cpan.strawberryperl.com then http://www.cpan.org and succeeded. All the rest was identically the same. **About PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot**, the same, failed to install from http://cpan.strawberryperl.com switched to http://www.cpan.org, succeeded downloading but failed install. About versions, check **UPDATE 3**. Also from cpan install logs: Mine ```P::G::G v2.021, gnuplot v5.4, Perl v5.032001```, Yours ```P::G::G v2.021, gnuplot v5.2, Perl v5.032001```

Comment: In Edge downloaded a module from cpan.strawberryperl.com, the browser redirected to cpan.strawberryperl.com, then to cpan.pair.com, then downloaded. Seems like ```LWP::UserAgent``` can't handle these redirects. Then, on new/clean Strawberry Perl changed ```http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/``` to ```http://cpan.pair.com/``` in ```perlhome\perl\lib\CPAN\Config.pm``` and installed ```PDL::Graphics::Simple```. No LWP failures. But runtime failing identically. Also identically same installation errors for ```PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot```, excepting the missing LWP failures and retries.

Comment: *"gnuplot v5.4"* : It is interesting that you have version 5.4, whereas I have version 5.2. I believe Strawberry Perl (PDL edition) comes with version 5.2. How did you install version 5.4? What is the output of running `where gnuplot` ? Here I have `gnuplot` installed in subdirectory `c\bin` of the Strawberry Perl directory.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Mine is not in subdiectory of the Strawberry Perl. The one which I am refering as perlhome, the gnuplot is installed in perlhome\..\gnuplot\bin. I have there Julia which is very ok with gnuplot, never had to take care about that.

Comment: *"gnuplot is installed in perlhome*" I think that might confuse PDL. Could you try using the gnuplot that comes with perl instead? Set the `GNUPLOT_BINARY` environment variable to the path of gnuplot (as shown [here](https://metacpan.org/release/ETJ/Alien-Gnuplot-1.034/source/lib/Alien/Gnuplot.pm#L177)) then reinstall `Alien::Gnuplot`. See if that helps.

Comment: @HåkonHægland thank you. After your suggestion I did the other way, as I always try to minimize steps. Deployed a new clean Strawberry Perl. In command line removed the path to **gnuplot** from system PATH variable. Then downloaded gnuplot stable zip packagee mingw edition for windows, and unpacked bin folder into ```perlhome\strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-PDL\perl\bin```.  Then did ```cpan PDL::Graphics::Simple``` and ```cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot``` and that solved all, it was much enough. All installed ok and worked fine.

Comment: You should put that as an actual answer. Also, I have no idea why you've made a separate question since the previous one is apparently solved by the answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to skip directly to **UPDATE 1**, and if doesn't work try from the beginning.

Following suggestion from @Ed, I separated the answer from the question.
As a long try&fail. With assistance from @HåkonHægland.
Note: The [documentation for PDL specifies](https://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps) only the step N4 from enumerated here. Everything else is not part of documentation. This discrepancy is not something that is actually expected (!!). When starting perldl I see such a remark:
[image]
On a software that pretends to be scientific, this looks rather like an excuse why pdl does not work, and documentation is inconsistent.

##########################################
**First solution** which worked, but on a clean new Windows 11 laptop did not work, so I don't expect it to work on other clean platform  either.
The steps to perform:

1. Prepare clean new system. Not that critical, the step N3 should be much enough to avoid interference.
2. Deployed a new clean Perl, latest versions. Probably not that significative, but I unpacked clean new "strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-PDL" for windows, zip package, no msi, from [strawberry perl](https://strawberryperl.com/). Suppose unpacked here **perlhome**
3. In the command line removed the path to gnuplot from system %PATH% variable. If there is no gluplot remnants this step is not required. It can be done globally, or locally in same command line you execute the remaining steps.
4. Downloaded gnuplot stable zip package mingw edition for windows, from [official gnuplot site](http://www.gnuplot.info/). Unpacked the bin folder into **perlhome**\perl\bin, without overwriting existing dlls.
5. Executed `cpan PDL::Graphics::Simple` in command line.
6. Executed `cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot` in command line.

Note, steps 5 and 6 shown some lwp failures while downloading, but not really critical. The lwp was failing one source, then downloading from alternative resource.

##########################################
**Update 1:** On a clean new system, Windows 11, but I expect will work for any other system. The steps to perform are similar to above ones, with small difference, add to the path variable the c++ compiler the which comes with the perl package, also step 4, unpacking the gnuplot, must be done at the very end, not before deploying packages from steps 5, 6:
The above steps did not work, so do not follow them. Maybe is even better to do the following steps, on a separated system, so you will create a perl+pdl+gnuplot portable, ready to run from a stick or an external drive, or copy and run where it is needed.

1. The new computer, was already clean
2. Deployed a new clean from [strawberry perl](https://strawberryperl.com/), unpacked "strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit-PDL" for windows, zip package, no msi. Suppose unpacked here **perlhome**. Note, this is portable edition+PDL, meaning it is meant to just copy and work, for instance on a memory stick. Set the path to Perl `set path=%path%;perlhome\perl\bin` if is not added to system.
3. Strawberry perl comes with C/C++ compiler. **perlhome**\c\bin, so add it to the environment PATH variable `set path=%path%;perlhome\c\bin`. Note, using any other external tool may lead, and will lead to abberations during install.
4. Do nothing, meaning do not unpack gnuplot so far, because it will lead to further failures in deployment of PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot.
5. Executed `cpan PDL::Graphics::Simple` in command line.
6. Executed `cpan PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot` in command line. So far installation executed successfully, but PDL Graphics still will not work.
7. Download gnuplot stable zip package mingw edition for windows, from [official gnuplot site](http://www.gnuplot.info/). Unpacked the bin folder into **perlhome**\perl\bin, without overwriting existing dlls.
   Now it works, but I still do not understand why still I see the error about PDL::Graphics::PGPLOT::Window. Using PDL AutoLoader doesn't fix this error.
   [image]

Trying to use cpan to install PDL::Graphics::PGPLOT::Window fails. I must emphasize, I installed gnuplot under Julia and that works exactly as is specified in the documentation, is self sufficient, has no interference with system no matter what. Nothing required to dig in, guess, investigate, documentation is high quality, and so is the support.

Comment: I am further suggesting that this whole question & answer be integrated with the original question, so it forms a coherent whole, and this q & a then be deleted.